# WPF C#4.0 Progressbar Help While Conducting Search

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls, progress-bar

I have a WPF C#4.0 application and it runs without problem. I need the simple code allows the progress bar to run only while the application is conducting it's search. I don't want it to run the whole time the application is running just when it is conducting a search from a search button. So I am not sure IsIndeterminate would work since it runs the whole time the application is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [IsIndeterminate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.progressbar.isindeterminate.aspx) property just means that the ProgressBar doesn't have a min or max value, but continually scrolls.

A ProgressBar doesn't "run".  It just does what it says - reports progress.  It's up to you to feed it values (Minimum, Maximum, Value) if you are not using the IsIndeterminate property.

It is impossible to give you a good answer without knowing more about your design, but if you are interested in actually showing a (known) progress, then take a look at the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class (or search SO for examples).

If you don't know the actual progress, and with "Search" you probably don't, then you can use IsIndeterminate as a Poor Man's "Busy - Please Wait".  Simply change the Visibility property appropriately when you start and finish searching.